# Cross reference to custom defined environment

Tags: cross-referencing

I've defined a theorem like environment ("Claim") and I want to cross reference it. However, this seems not to be working as I get [image]

after the customary two runs. My code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}

\begin{document}

\begin{claim}
  \label{prop_sols}
  This is my claim.
\end{claim}

Note that the reference to the previous claim (\ref{prop_sols]}) doesn't compile.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have `\ref{prop_sols]}`. The `]` shouldn't be there.